# Double the fun with two puzzles

Tags: logical-deduction

Here are the two puzzles that I have heard a long ago from my friends.

> 1) You can touch it with your right hand, but not with your left hand. What is it?
>
> 2) 10x+4x = 2y Then, what is x and y?

> HINT: (x and y are not numbers)

I think both the puzzles are easy for you.

*`+1 if only one correct answer. +1 and will mark as accepted answer if both answers are correct.`*

Comment: 1) Your left elbow. 2) "xy", variables, or letters.

Comment: Only one question per question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your left elbow.
2. $y$ is a week. $x$ is a day.

Comment: OH YA??? *Twists hand creepily*

Answer (score 2):

1) Your left elbow.

2) 'x' means eggs; y is a box of seven eggs.

Comment: +1. You were almost there. Would have given +2 if possible :(

Comment: I don't see why this isn't correct. For all we know $y$ is *anything* that is 7 times $x$. This answer fits all the requirements of the puzzle, and was earlier than the other answer, which was no better than this.

Comment: @AeJey - This is a good point (thanks mdc32!). Why is Joe's answer more 'correct' than mine?

Comment: @randal'thor: because, in your answer, 10 eggs + 4 eggs gives 2 boxes of seven eggs, the two boxes are extra, Which were not in the left hand side of the expression making the equation wrong.

Comment: @mdc32: In rand's answer,  apply the values in the equation. We get, ~10 eggs + 4 eggs = 2 boxes of seven eggs~. That is, in left hand side, there are 14 eggs and right hand side, there are 14 eggs and 2 boxes. Which contradicts.

Comment: @mdc32: On the accepted answer, left hand side has 14 days and right hand side has 2 weeks which is definitely 14 days. Nothing extra. So it satisfies the equation.

Comment: @AeJey - So if I'd said 'a collection of 7 eggs' without including the box, my answer would have been right?

Comment: @randal'thor: Yes. It will be better. But it's not better than the accepted answer. For an argument you can say that 14 eggs is same as 2 collections of 7 eggs. But just forget the puzzle. If somebody gave you 14 eggs and told you to count, they will think there is something wrong with you if you answer two collection of 7 eggs. But if you take 14 days. It is definitely 2 weeks and there is nothing wrong in it at any context. I didn't mean your answer is wrong. It's technically correct. But the accepted answer is the best so far.